# which data type i must choose for boolean type field?

Tags: oracle

I wanna create a Boolean field in my oracle table but I seen there is no boolean or byte data type so,which one of the oracle data type I must choose for a boolean value?

answer:
I find how Oracle developer do this by wisard:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE17
(
  COLUMN1 CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  COLUMN2 VARCHAR2(4000)
)
;
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Have you checked the related questions as they seem to cover this?

Comment: I use oracle 6 and 10g.I cant find any related question in oracle :(

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are looking for "y" or "n" you can use CHAR(1)

Comment: I prefer this because you can often get away with showing it as is in reports.

Comment: You can also use a check constraint to enforce that it only contains one of the valid values. And if you name the field something like VALID_YN it is obvious that it should be YN rather than, say, T(rue)/F(alse).

Answer (score 1):

You can use char(1) or number(1)

If you use number(1), set 0-False and 1-True as many programming languages 1 & 0 for Boolean