# Boolean giving invalid datatype - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table in Oracle SQL Developer but I am getting error ORA-00902.

Here is my schema for the table creation

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT(
    Appointment NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
            PatientID NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
            DateOfVisit DATE NOT NULL,
            PhysioName VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
            MassageOffered BOOLEAN NOT NULL, <-- the line giving the error -->
            CONSTRAINT APPOINTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (Appointment)
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: supported data types: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#i45441

Comment: See here for a discussion of what to do since there is no boolean type in tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle does not support the `boolean` data type at schema level, though it is supported in PL/SQL blocks. By schema level, I mean you cannot create table columns with type as `boolean`, nor nested table types of records with one of the columns as `boolean`. You have that freedom in PL/SQL though, where you can create a record type collection with a boolean column.

As a workaround I would suggest use `CHAR(1 byte)` type, as it will take just one byte to store your value, as opposed to two bytes for `NUMBER` format. Read more about data types and sizes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209) on Oracle Docs.

Answer (score 10):

Last I heard there were no `boolean` type in oracle. Use `number(1)` instead!

Comment: Only in SQL, in PLSQL there is

Answer (score 4):

Oracle doesn't support boolean for table column datatype. You should probably use a CHAR(1) (Y/N)

You can see more info on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30062/1385896)

Answer (score 0):

i think u  got a below good result

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG

Answer (score 0):

When using an Entity class to create the schema, defining the boolean value as below will help

> ```
> @Column(columnDefinition = "number default 0")
> private boolean picked;
> ```