# Boolean field is always true

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

My field looks like this:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Number(1,0) default '1'")
protected Boolean developersVisible;
```

When i get the object from the database, the value is always `true`. No matter whats in the database (null, 0 , 1)

I'm using a Oracle Database

**Solved!**

I did not commit when i changed the values via the sqldeveloper

I accepted Óscars answer because it was really helpful

Comment: why not look at the SQL being invoked?

Comment: @DataNucleus the select looks normal

Comment: @PhilippSander you need to check the Selects, inserts/updates and queries for autogenerating the table schema.

Comment: i updated the values via db and didn't insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `columnDefinition` attribute in this case, it's not necessary and it might be messing with the mapping of the field. And the `default 1` part explains why you're always getting a `true` value. Try this:

```
@Column
protected Boolean developersVisible = Boolean.TRUE;
```

Comment: but i want all value to be true when i add the column

Comment: @PhilippSander see my update, that's how you create a default value. Avoid `columnDefinition` unless strictly necessary, it will affect the portability of the code

Comment: this is not setting `true`or `1` for all entries (it's setting `null` when i add the field (i deleted it and created the column again)

Comment: @PhilippSander maybe there's something wrong with the way you're persisting the entity?

Comment: i did not persist yet, just added the column!

Comment: @PhilippSander The field will get set to true at the moment you call the constructor, it has nothing to do with JPA or persistence, it's just the way Java handles attribute initialization. It's impossible to tell without seeing the complete code, but there must be something incorrect in it

Comment: now the field is always null, no matter whats in the database. which is a step back

Comment: @PhilippSander as I said: the problem is not in the column definition, that part is correct, the problem is somewhere else in your code

Comment: i'll have a look at it! but thanks for correcting my annotation!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use another column definition, like a `CHAR`?
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle) for details.

Comment: no! that would create a dependency to the database. i know that oracle has no Boolean or Bit. It's JPAs job to handle that (imho)

Comment: You can be sure that your current code (with the current columnDefinition) also creates a dependency to the database (e.g. MySql does not have such a column type `Number`). Please change your question and note you do not want DB dependency. In this case, Oscar's answer is definitely a good one.

Comment: i already did this. and getting rid of the dependency was one point why i did this