# READ XML BOOLEAN Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, boolean

How to read Boolean values from XML Column in SQL. Below is sample code. Is it achievable using XQuery Value function.

```
 DECLARE @XML XML = '<form>
                     <field name="BAR_prior_report" type="Boolean"><value>false</value></field>
                      <field name="BAR_multiple_branches" type="Boolean"><value>true</value></field>
                  </form>'
```

i would like to see BAR_prior_report as False and BAR_multiple_branches as True

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will return the fields as `BIT` columns, which most languages will parse as a boolean (there is no boolean in SqlServer).

```
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('(field[@name="BAR_prior_report"]/value)[1]', 'bit') 
    AS BAR_prior_report,
  Nodes.node.value('(field[@name="BAR_multiple_branches"]/value)[1]', 'bit') 
    AS BAR_multiple_branches
FROM
  @XML.nodes('//form') AS Nodes(node);
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32574)

You can always pass this through another projection for further processing, e.g. [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32578)

Comment: There's no boolean in Oracle as well, so the OP may have to decode the values to a varchar2 (e.g. 'TRUE' or 'FALSE') or maybe '1' or '0' depending on his/her preference.
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle and https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595