# wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DROP_QUEUE_TABLE'

Tags: java, oracle, parameter-passing, jdbctemplate, advanced-queuing

I am trying to drop a queue using jdbcTemplate().update method. which is -

```
getJdbcTemplate().update("call DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE (?, ?)", qTableName.toUpperCase(),true);
```

DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE takes two parameters. 1) queue_table as string and 2) force as boolean.

whn I try to run the above code, I am getting -

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [call DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE (?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DROP_QUEUE_TABLE'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DROP_QUEUE_TABLE'
```

but when I am running the following code it works fine-

```
getJdbcTemplate().update("call DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (?, ?)", qTableName.toUpperCase(), payloadType.toUpperCase());
```

What I am guessing is, the problem is passing oracle objects (which are not varchar or int) as parameters.

I really wnat to know is there any way to solve this.

Comment: True is not an Oracle boolean... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

BOOLEAN parameters are [not supported](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/tips3.htm#1005343).
As recomended write your own wrapper procedure with int parameter or pass a  PL/SQL block with fixed TRUE parameter:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE( 
      queue_table        => ?, 
      force              => TRUE); 
END;
```

Comment: I couldnt find any solution to this, I looked in to aqapi classes, what I found was they used callable statements, and executed anonymous procedures.

Comment: They cocatenated the parameters in the query string. Ultimately I was forced to do the same in my code.