# Restrict only '1' and '0' value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working in Oracle SQL and I am trying to constrain the integer datatype to only take the values 0 and 1 (for an active item or not).

This is what I currently have:

```
    CREATE TABLE ACTIVE_EX (
        ACTIVE int NOT NULL 
           CONSTRAINT check_active_ind CHECK (ACTIVE = 0 OR ACTIVE = 1)
    );

    SELECT * FROM ACTIVE_EX;
    INSERT INTO ACTIVE_EX(ACTIVE)values(2);
```

When I enter this command and run the `Select * from ACTIVE_EX` line, the value 2 will still be entered into the table with no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean Field in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062/boolean-field-in-oracle)

Comment: That's something called `BIT`.

Comment: @Eric when I try that datatype, it gives me an error that it is an invalid datatype

Comment: Your column is called `ACTIVE`, but your constraint is referring to `ACTIVE_IND`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog oops, that was a typo. in my actual code they're the same

Comment: You will have to provide a full example. I used a constraint exactly like yours and it restricts the values just fine.

Comment: Because you did not provided a full example, so check whether your constraint is `Enable`: `SELECT STATUS FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE LOWER (CONSTRAINT_NAME) = 'check_active_ind';`
Your constraint should work fine.

Comment: is it even possible to create column with `int` data type in Oracle?

Comment: @Maxim Yes, Oracle DB supports INT datatype.

Comment: @Ikrom as I remember INTEGER was available only in PL/SQL

Comment: @Maxim Yes, correct, but Oracle recognizes the ANSI or IBM datatype name that differs from the Oracle Database datatype name. It converts the datatype to the equivalent Oracle datatype, records the Oracle datatype as the name of the column datatype, and stores the column data in the Oracle datatype based on the conversions. On the ^above example INT will be converted to NUMBER, if we create a table with INT data type then, in fact, it's converted to NUMBER datatype.
`Details here:` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213

Comment: thx for the link

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out why I was getting that error... I forgot to drop the table after running it the first time and making changes again

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (active int not null
  3       constraint ch_active check (active in (0, 1))
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into test values (-1);
insert into test values (-1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ACTIVE) violated


SQL> insert into test values (2);
insert into test values (2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ACTIVE) violated


SQL> insert into test values (100);
insert into test values (100)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ACTIVE) violated


SQL> insert into test values (0.3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (1.2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (3.8);
insert into test values (3.8)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ACTIVE) violated


SQL> select * From test;

    ACTIVE
----------
         0
         1

SQL>
```

As you can see, decimal values between 0 and 1 can be entered, but will be rounded so the final result will still be 0 or 1.

Comment: Did you review my example? Values I tried t insert? Which one of them doesn't suite your needs? You said you managed to enter "2" into *your* table - I can't do that with *mine*, so ... could you explain what's wrong with such a constraint?

Comment: Yes I have the exact structure typed in as you. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm writing my select statements in the same file as the one I'm creating it in?

Comment: No, it doesn't / shouldn't.

Comment: @PythonSOS Can you just check whether your constraint is `ENABLED`?

`SELECT  CONSTRAINT_NAME, STATUS, DEFERRABLE, DEFERRED, VALIDATED FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE LOWER (CONSTRAINT_NAME) = 'check_active_ind';`

Comment: @Ikrom Nothing appears in the data grid when I run that line

Comment: @Ikrom, constraint that is created "right now" is most probably enabled, so - I wouldn't insist on that (though, I might be wrong. You'd rather be sure than sorry, I agree).

Comment: @PythonSOS OR 
1. run the script without `WHERE` clause and check whether the constraint is there.
2. Are you running the script from the schema where the table/constraint was created? If NO => query `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` or `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: @Ikrom yes, everything is being run in the same file as where the table is created

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes, correct, but just to make sure that it was not disabled or was created properly... let's see...

Comment: I'd suggest you (PythonSOS) to run exactly the same code I posted. Then copy/paste output from SQL*Plus window into your question (i.e. edit it), so that we'd see what is going on.

Comment: I'm writing the code in Toad for Oracle just FYI if that helps

Comment: Nope, as its GUI prevents us from seeing what you did and how Oracle responded, command by command.

Comment: @PythonSOS It should not matter which tool, if the constraint was created (Status=Enabled) and you can see that by using the script then it should force.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's impossible that such a basic functionality doesn't work. so only two options are possible: the constraint hasn't been created or enabled

Comment: When I run my code through sql*plus, there is an error on my first variable (id int not null) stating that it is an invalid identifier